# How often does Mars appear at the horizon in our sky?

Tags: mars, conjunction

How frequently does Mars appear at the horizon in a year(It need not be visible. It just need to be at the horizon)? How long does it take from one of these events to the next one? How long does Mars take to pass over the horizon? Are there specific places where this phenomenon is visible in the sky? Are there places where this phenomenon is never visible in the sky? If standing on a point on earth it is possible to draw a line to Mars without hitting anything other than atmosphere and assuming that I am at a point where I was able to do this with Mars at the horizon. What is the probability that I will be able to draw the same line towards the horizon from the same point and hit Mars again some other day?

Comment: When you say "appears" do you mean visible to the naked eye, or just that it is technically there?  There's a fairly large range of days when it's not visible because it is completely drowned out by the brightness of the sun.

If you just mean "possible to draw a line to it without hitting anything other than atmosphere" then the number is pretty close to 365 days, twice a day (morning and evening), barring the days when the sun (or moon) is literally in the way.

Comment: i did not mean visible. My question was if it was there at all. But what about the rest? How long does it generally stay in that position? Will I be able to see this from all points on earth? Or are there places where the skies don't see Mars on the horizon?

Comment: I have another question regarding ""possible to draw a line to it without hitting anything other than atmosphere." Assuming that I am at a point where I was able to do this with Mars at the horizon. What is the probability that i will be able to draw the same line towards the horizon from the point and hit Mars again?

Comment: This question might be better suited on SE Astronomy

Answer (score 1):

Twice daily, as the earth rotates. This occurs no matter where you are.

The time between transitions varies on the observers location. Close to the equator, it is approx 12hrs between transitions, with this becoming skewed to a short and a long time between transitions, for example, 3hrs and 21hrs for an observer far north or south.

Mars orbital plane is inclined compared to earths rotational plane, therefore Mars crossing the horizon will be visible from all points (unlike the sun). The actual transition time will be quite short depending on where the viewer is located, short close to the equator (a little under 2 seconds), longer closer to the poles (I'm not sure of an upward bound, less than a few minutes I'd guess, given a perfectly smooth horizon).

The transition will be at a very slightly different point on the horizon each time, and doesn't repeat for a very long time (hundreds of years, due to mars orbit length, and earths year not being an exact multiple of its day length. You might need telescopes to measure this though).

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you are looking to have a celestial event which takes place at a specific frequency or under conditions you define, may I suggest worldbuilding.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Twice daily, as the earth rotates. This occurs no matter where you are." Technically, that is not accurate. Depending on the declination of Mars and the latitude of the observer, there are regions near the Earth's poles where Mars does not rise or set. (Mars may not rise or set when approximately when closer to the poles than the artic circles.)